# Unbale to use Q(lowercase) key after a failed key-binding effort

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I tried to use the Alt-q combination to set as a shortcut for opening 'terminator' using ***gconf -> metacity-> global keybindings***. But it did not work. The problem now is that my 'q' key on the keyboard doesn't work (I am copy pasting 'q' here). Funny thing is that 'Q' still works fine. I am unable to track the fault. I have reset all the keybindings and reset the system many times, but all in vain. What can be done in this regard?

Comment: What did you set in gconf? Did you reset it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of things that did not work, I finally purged Xbindkeys (which I had installed in between and may have created the conflict) and terminator. After a reboot, the 'q' key is working fine now.